# Alibaba Cloud 3rd party firewall

Tags: alibaba-cloud

What is the scenario in which a client wants to use Fortinet Firewalls or Palo Alto Networs Firewall in Alibaba Cloud in their cloud implementation?

Answer (score 0):

- Having a third-party firewall could enhance your security on the cloud, as it can provide multiple layers of protection and more controls.
- Both firewalls have native integration with Alibaba Cloud, so it can further improve your VPC and security groups with application/host-level segmentation and policies.
- If you're already using them, you're already familiar with it, and it makes it easier to integrate with other products of the same ecosystem, such as FortiGate + FortiSandbox + FortiClient EMS.
- Compliance requirement, such as PCI DSS.
- You can bring your own license (BYOL) to use on Alibaba Cloud.
- Both have their own features. You can read more about [Palo Alto](https://www.boll.ch/datasheets/VM_Series_on_Alibaba_Cloud.pdf) and [FortiGate](https://www.fortinet.com/content/dam/fortinet/assets/data-sheets/FortiGate_VM_AliCloud.pdf) features. Here are some notable features:

  - IPsec VPN
  - Threat prevention (IPS)
  - Application and traffic control
  - Antivirus/Malware detection
  - Vulnerability management
  - High Avaliability (HA)

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend you use the 3rd party firewall on Alibaba Cloud. It is better to use the original Cloud firewall.

The 3rd party firewall could only put on the network entrance and exit. It would not 100% integrate with 100% Alibaba Cloud service. Sometimes it may have a lot of false-positive alarms.